# Customizing Metro App Touch Functionality

Tags: c#, visual-studio, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps

I would like to customize the touch-based functionality of my Windows 8 Metro app such that in a flip view, one can not only swipe from left to right with one finger but two fingers while keeping zoom functionality (currently, with zooming enabled, two fingers causes the image to shrink or grow in size rather than go to the next or previous item). As is, all of the code controlling touch behavior seems to be abstracted by the framework; is there a way I can go about accomplishing this fine-tuning?

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce an entire app in a Machine But can Advice you to go through Gestures in windows 8.

Add an event to the swipe gesture and if require(if id does not get zoomed before swiping) change the selected index of the flip view Accordingly.

[gestures in windows store app](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj883700.aspx)

**Note**: in worst case if swipe gestures also takes the zoom, please debug and see if you can recognize a right to left gesture or a left to right and change flip view selected index